# Table structure garbled during migration

Tags: tables, geometry, sidewaystable

I am writing my thesis now. I tried to accommodate a one-page table from my publication to my thesis which belongs to different classes and column structures. The publication was using

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
```

while my thesis is using

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,a4paper,11pt,oneside, 
  chapterprefix=true,sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}
```

The code I used in the journal was same as in the thesis which is written below-

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,a4paper,11pt,oneside,
   chapterprefix=true,sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}
%Table packages
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

%%%BIG TABLE BEGIN

\begin{sidewaystable*}
\caption{Comparison among state of the art designs}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1in}
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.75in}
                             c
                             c
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.75in}
                             c
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5in}
                             X}
\toprule
\thead{Reference}&\thead{Sensors}&\thead{Dedicated.}&\thead{No. of\\ sensors}&\thead{Method}&\thead{Accuracy. \\ in \%}&\thead{Features}&\thead{Limitations}\\
\midrule\\

\textcite{Er2018}
  & Sound sensor, accelerometer
    & Yes & $>1$ & Non-ambulatory & 92
      & Fuzzy logic based dual detection capability
        & Indoor only, no location information, costly and non-portable solution.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{He2020}
  & RFID and Radar
    & Yes & $>1$ & Non-ambulatory & 94
      &Increased detection area up to 230\% compared to traditional systems.
        &Indoor only, no location information, costly and non-portable solution. Implementation requires specialized training.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{VanThanh2018}
  & Proprietary accelerometer
    & Yes & 1 & Wearable sensor & 92
      &Fall as well as post fall posture recognition.
        &Costly and bulky, no local processing on device, no text based warning SMS.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{Zhang2020}
  &Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Magnetometer
    & Yes & $>1$ & Wearable sensor & 96
      & Fall and post fall posture recognition. Warning SMS with location.
        &Costly and bulky, no local processing on device, no text based warning SMS.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{Zurbuchen2020}
  & Accelerometer Gyroscope
    & Yes & $>1$ & Wearable sensor & 97
      & Multiclass fall and ADL detection.
        & High initial cost, separate device, no local processing on device, no manual mode.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{Yu2017}
  & Camera
    & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 96
      & Posture based detection (Laying is treated as fall).
        & High initial cost, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{juang2015fall}
  & Camera
    & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 100
      & Human joint identification along with fall.
        & High initial cost, no local processing on device,low portability, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues. no manual mode and no local dataset used.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{zhang2020human}
  & Camera
    & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 98 &
      Fall detection based on body posture, local dataset used.
        & High initial cost, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{shu2021eight}
  & Camera
    & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 94
      & Multi genre fall detection using eight cameras.
        & High initial cost,low portability, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues.\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{sidewaystable*}
%%%BIG TABLE END

\end{document}
```

which is suppose to give the output as

[image: Desired output]

However, it is not only chopping off the header now but the entire structure is now garbled as shown below. Please help.

[image: Garbled output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your thesis document missing a statement of how wide the margins are, i.e., maybe something like

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

If I insert this instruction in your code, apply a few minor fixes to your code, and run `\providecommand\textcite[1]{}` to avoid getting lots of warning messages, I get the following result which, to my eyes at least, doesn't look bad.

[image]

```
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\documentclass[listof=totoc,a4paper,11pt,oneside,
   chapterprefix=true,sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % <-- new

%Table packages
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
%\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx, ragged2e}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}

\providecommand\textcite[1]{} % ??

\begin{document}

%%%BIG TABLE BEGIN

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt

\caption{Comparison among state of the art designs}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}%
  l 
  %P{1in}
  P{0.95in}
  c
  c
  P{1.1in}
  c
  P{1.5in}
  L @{}}
  
\toprule
Reference &
Sensors &
Dedicated &
\thead{No. of\\ sensors}&
Method&
\thead{Accuracy\\ in \%}&
Features&
Limitations\\

\midrule

\textcite{Er2018}
  & Sound sensor, accelerometer
  & Yes & $>1$ & Non-ambulatory & 92
  & Fuzzy logic based dual detection capability
  & Indoor only, no location information, costly and non-portable solution.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{He2020}
  & RFID and Radar
  & Yes & $>1$ & Non-ambulatory & 94
  & Increased detection area up to 230\% compared to traditional systems.
  & Indoor only, no location information, costly and non-portable solution. Implementation requires specialized training.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{VanThanh2018}
  & Proprietary accelerometer
  & Yes & $\phantom{{}>}1$ & Wearable sensor & 92
  & Fall as well as post fall posture recognition.
  & Costly and bulky, no local processing on device, no text based warning SMS.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{Zhang2020}
  & Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Magnetometer
  & Yes & $>1$ & Wearable sensor & 96
  & Fall and post fall posture recognition. Warning SMS with location.
  & Costly and bulky, no local processing on device, no text based warning SMS.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{Zurbuchen2020}
  & Accelerometer Gyroscope
  & Yes & $>1$ & Wearable sensor & 97
  & Multiclass fall and ADL detection.
  & High initial cost, separate device, no local processing on device, no manual mode.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{Yu2017}
  & Camera
  & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 96
  & Posture based detection (Laying is treated as fall).
  & High initial cost, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{juang2015fall}
  & Camera
  & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 100
  & Human joint identification along with fall.
  & High initial cost, no local processing on device, low portability, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues, no manual mode and no local dataset used.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{zhang2020human}
  & Camera
  & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 98 
  & Fall detection based on body posture, local dataset used.
  & High initial cost, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{shu2021eight}
  & Camera
  & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 94
  & Multi genre fall detection using eight cameras.
  & High initial cost, low portability, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues.\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{sidewaystable}
%%%BIG TABLE END

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks mico, the geometry package had the option [pass, a4paper]. Now with \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} this one is solved. However, I need to check it's effect on other chapters. Update: Another table garbled. Opening a separate question for that.

Comment: @Bukaida - You're most welcome. Do check with the powers that be what is and isn't allowed regarding page sizes and margins for your thesis.

Answer (score 1):

Your table is simply too big at normal size to fit in a page.

You're also using too much space for the headers in columns that otherwise would be quite narrow. I suggest that both last two columns are allocated as `X`.

```
\documentclass[
  listof=totoc,
  a4paper,
  11pt,
  oneside,
  chapterprefix=true,
  sfdefaults=false,
]{scrbook}

%Table packages
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

%%%BIG TABLE BEGIN

\begin{sidewaystable*}
\footnotesize

\captionabove{Comparison among state of the art designs}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
  @{}
  P{0.75in}
  P{0.75in}
  c
  c
  P{0.75in}
  c
  L
  L
  @{}
}
\toprule
\thead{Reference}&\thead{Sensors}&\thead{D}&\thead{N}&\thead{Method}&
  \thead{A}&\thead{Features}&\thead{Limitations}\\
\midrule\\

\textcite{Er2018}
  & Sound sensor, accelerometer
    & Yes & $>1$ & Non-ambulatory & 92
      & Fuzzy logic based dual detection capability
        & Indoor only, no location information, costly and non-portable solution.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{He2020}
  & RFID and Radar
    & Yes & $>1$ & Non-ambulatory & 94
      &Increased detection area up to 230\% compared to traditional systems.
        &Indoor only, no location information, costly and non-portable solution. Implementation requires specialized training.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{VanThanh2018}
  & Proprietary accelerometer
    & Yes & 1 & Wearable sensor & 92
      &Fall as well as post fall posture recognition.
        &Costly and bulky, no local processing on device, no text based warning SMS.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{Zhang2020}
  &Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Magnetometer
    & Yes & $>1$ & Wearable sensor & 96
      & Fall and post fall posture recognition. Warning SMS with location.
        &Costly and bulky, no local processing on device, no text based warning SMS.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{Zurbuchen2020}
  & Accelerometer Gyroscope
    & Yes & $>1$ & Wearable sensor & 97
      & Multiclass fall and ADL detection.
        & High initial cost, separate device, no local processing on device, no manual mode.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{Yu2017}
  & Camera
    & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 96
      & Posture based detection (Laying is treated as fall).
        & High initial cost, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{juang2015fall}
  & Camera
    & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 100
      & Human joint identification along with fall.
        & High initial cost, no local processing on device,low portability, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues. no manual mode and no local dataset used.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{zhang2020human}
  & Camera
    & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 98 &
      Fall detection based on body posture, local dataset used.
        & High initial cost, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor.\\
\addlinespace

\textcite{shu2021eight}
  & Camera
    & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 94
      & Multi genre fall detection using eight cameras.
        & High initial cost,low portability, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues.\\

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{8}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{D = Dedicated, N = Number of Sensors, A = Accuracy in \%}
\end{tabularx}

\end{sidewaystable*}
%%%BIG TABLE END

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first column should not overfill when the references have been properly processed.